# $2x'(t)=x(1/t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose that

$$2x'(t)=x(1/t), t>0 \text{ and } x(1)=2$$

Show that x(t) satisfies the equation

$$t^2 x''(t) + at x'(t) + bx(t)=0$$

And find the solution of the form $ c t^n$

**My attempt**

It is clear that the solution is $c \sqrt{t}$ but I found this just looking for the equation. First, I've tried to find this making a change of variables s=1/t and got

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{-1}{t^2} \frac{dx}{ds} = \frac{1}{2}x(s)$$

But this gave me the wrong solution. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: See the condition

Comment: Sorry. I meant $x(t)=2\sqrt t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your assumption you have $2x'(1/t)=x(t)$ (replace $t$ with $1/t$). Then, if you differentiate the initial ODE you have

$2x''(t)=-\frac{1}{t^2}x'(1/t)=-\frac{1}{2t^2}x(t)$.

Thus, your ODE is

$t^2x''(t)+\frac{1}{4}x(t)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

why not take the derivative of $2x'(t) = x(1/t)$ noting that $x'(1/t) = \frac 12 x(t).$ i get $$2x''(t) = x'(1/t) \times -\frac 1 {t^2}=-\frac{x(t)}{2t^2}\to4t^2 x''(t)+x(t) =0. $$

now try solutions of the form $$x = t^k \to x' = kt^{k-1}, x'' = k(k-1)t^{k-2} \to 0=4k(k-1)+1=4k^2 - 4k + 1 =(2k-1)^2$$  solutions are $$ k = 1/2, 1/2. x = t^{1/2}, t^{1/2}\ln t$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $$x'(t)=x(1/t)/2,$$ derive with respect to $t$ one more time:

$$x''(t) = -\frac{x'(1/t)}{2t^2} = -\frac 14 \frac{x(t)}{t^2}.$$